# How can i extract the date and time from the html page file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the class i have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace SatelliteImages
{
    class ExtractImages
    {
        static WebClient client;
        List<string> imagesUrls = new List<string>();
        static string htmltoextract;
        static string link;
        static string text;
        public static List<string> countriescodes = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> countriesnames = new List<string>();
        private static int lastsatimage = 0;
        private static string Next_Sat_File;
        private static string temp_sat_dir;

        public void Init()
        {
            ExtractCountires();
        }

        public static void ExtractCountires()
        {
            try
            {
                htmltoextract = "http://sat24.com/en/?ir=true";
                client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadFile(htmltoextract, @"c:\temp\sat24.html");
                client.Dispose();

                string tag1 = "<li><a href=\"/en/";
                string tag2 = "</a></li>";

                string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\sat24.html");
                s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(tag1));
                s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(tag2) + tag2.ToCharArray().Length);
                s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "");

                string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] { tag1, tag2 }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


                string tag3 = "<li><ahref=\"/en/";

                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 17)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    string l = "";
                    if (parts[i].Contains(tag3))
                        l = parts[i].Replace(tag3, "");

                    string z1 = l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf('"'));
                    countriescodes.Add(z1);

                    string z2 = parts[i].Substring(parts[i].LastIndexOf('>') + 1);
                    countriesnames.Add(z2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found that when reading the sat24.html file in the file the dates and times are in this part in the html file:

```
var arrayImageTimes = [];
arrayImageTimes.push('201612271810');arrayImageTimes.push('201612271825');arrayImageTimes.push('201612271840');arrayImageTimes.push('201612271855');arrayImageTimes.push('201612271910');arrayImageTimes.push('201612271925');arrayImageTimes.push('201612271940');arrayImageTimes.push('201612271955');arrayImageTimes.push('201612272010');arrayImageTimes.push('201612272025');
```

Then what i want to do is to exctract the dates and times and to add them to two lists: 201612271810 So the first list will be of this format.

The second list to be of date and time not sure what format but: Year = 2016 month = 12 day = 27 hours = 18 minutes = 10

What i want to do later is to build a new link for each date and time the new links should be in this format: If we take for example the date and time 201612271810. Then: http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201612271810&ir=true The question is how can i extract the date and time and then using my ExtractCountries method to build the links. 
In the ExtractCountries method i'm getting two lists one the countries codes and one the countries names.

What i need to build the links is the country/ies codes and the country/ies date and time.

So then  i can use the list of codes with a date time for example:

The first list will be the dates and times as they are in the format in the html file: For example the first date and time is:

http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201612271810&ir=true

Where is = Israel and 201612271810 is the date time for this image link.
Or for example

```
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=tu&time=201612271810&ir=true
```

Region tu is turkey

so what i need is to get list of links built from all countries codes and all dates and times per region(countrey) so i can later download the images.

So in the list for example uri string type or string list type will be something like in first 10 indexs:

```
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=tu&time=201612271825&ir=true
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=tu&time=201612271840&ir=true
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=tu&time=201612271855&ir=true
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=tu&time=201612271910&ir=true
.
.
.
.
.
.
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201612271810&ir=true
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201612271825&ir=true
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201612271840&ir=true
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201612271910&ir=true
```

Ofcourse dpending on each region/country extracted date and time from the sat24 page.

Then when finished creating the list to download the images.Each link for example: http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201612271910&ir=true should be downloaded and saved as image.

Comment: You should use HTML Agility Pack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example using the agility pack to extract info from an html document.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();
        wc.BaseAddress = "http://sat24.com/";
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

        var temp = wc.DownloadData("/en");
        doc.Load(new MemoryStream(temp));       

        var secTokenScript = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
            .Where(e =>
                   String.Compare(e.Name, "script", true) == 0 &&
                   String.Compare(e.ParentNode.Name, "div", true) == 0 &&
                   e.InnerText.Length > 0 &&
                   e.InnerText.Trim().StartsWith("var region")
                  ).FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
        var securityToken = secTokenScript;
        securityToken = securityToken.Substring(0, securityToken.IndexOf("arrayImageTimes.push"));  
        securityToken = secTokenScript.Substring(securityToken.Length).Replace("arrayImageTimes.push('", "").Replace("')", "");
        var dates = securityToken.Trim().Split(new string[] { ";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var scriptDates = dates.Select(x => new ScriptDate { DateString = x });
        foreach(var date in scriptDates) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Date String: '" + date.DateString + "'\tYear: '" + date.Year + "'\t Month: '" + date.Month + "'\t Day: '" + date.Day + "'\t Hours: '" + date.Hours + "'\t Minutes: '" + date.Minutes + "'");
        }

    }


    public class ScriptDate
    {
        public string DateString {get;set;}
        public int Year 
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(0, 4));
            }
        }
        public int Month
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(4, 2));
            }
        }
        public int Day
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(6, 2));
            }
        }
        public int Hours
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(8, 2));
            }
        }
        public int Minutes
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(10, 2));
            }
        }




    }


}
```

I have also created a [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wX8wq8) showing that this works